# Can someone spoof the last modification date of an uploaded file?

Tags: php, shell

My server got compromosed, I found a file **ch.php** along with two other **.so** files uploaded inside the wp-includes/images/crystal folder of my wordpress site. The files uploaded through the shell were last modified recently. However, the ch.php has exactly the same last modification date of any other files on the server,

This makes me think that I have uploaded the shell by mistake along with other files. But suprisingly, in my local wamp folder the file doesn't exist.

Can someone spoof the last modification date to make me think that the file was uploaded by me? To what extent can I trust the last modification date that appears on Filezilla ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
touch -d "$(date -r filename) - 2 hours" filename
```

Comment: Damn. this makes the investigation even harder. Thank you

Comment: @ShikataGaNai - If you've got a local copy of the site, you can download the live version, and compare the two; that will show you any modified files. You'll also need to check the database, too, in case there are backdoors added in there.

Comment: Thank's for the hints. I didn't know backdoors could be hidden in database too.